# How do you do a 2-color border with css?

Tags: html, css

Le Code (without background): http://jsfiddle.net/SP6ny/ (colors changed for extra contrast)

Basically I have LI elements, and I need to add this border to them:
[image]

there is a pattern in the background so the list must not have a background.

thanks.

(I have no idea what I"m doing.)

```
body{
    background: black;
}
.rl_section{
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.rl_section:first-child;{
    border-top: none;
}
.rl_section:last-child;{
    border-bottom: none;
}
.rl_content{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaf;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a55;
    padding: 3px 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that an image?  You want the image to be the border, or are there double borders in the image that I can't see?

Comment: @TheLindyHop if you post what code you have already it will make it easier for us to answer you. And also, as bozdoz has pointed out, it's difficult to tell what's in the image. You should post a bigger image showing the full effect, and explain specifically what you are trying to do.

Comment: @TheLindyHop fix your question up a bit and I'll gladly +1 you.  It's a good question, it was just difficult to understand what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a technique like this: http://jsfiddle.net/sl1dr/Hub86/

Basically I am using top and bottom borders with differing colors.

Comment: that would work, except I need it above and below the first and last elements respectivly

Comment: Ah, simply add the border to the ul as well then. I have updated the link in my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Remove the first-child and last-child styles and add borders to the top and bottom of the ul element: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/Hub86/9/

Answer (score 0):

Make the background of the container of the LI elements black. Make a margin-top:1px; on the LI elements themselves. then a border-top:1px solid {#YOUR COLOR CODE}; on the elements.

Comment: That doesn't quite get the inset effect in the image.

Comment: If the OP provided a clearer/larger image and/or a more detailed explanation, I would have a better idea of what the desired effect is.

Comment: yeah, background has to be transparent

Comment: @TheLindyHop notice how your question is rapidly being voted down. This is an indicator that you need to fix it. The fact that you are responding in comments but not addressing people's issues with your question is probably making it even worse...

Comment: I fixed the question, but I think the answer is in @joshuanhibbert's question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the outline propperty for 1 color and border for the other

```
li {
outline: 1px gray solid;
border: 1px black solid;
}
```